# Excel Column Widths Cannot be Set to 0.25", Automatically Reverts to 0.27"

Tags: excel, vba, width, cell

I am having trouble sizing cells in Excel. When I try to resize a range of cells or even an individual cell on a specific page in my workbook, I cannot set the cell width to 0.25", or 24 pixels. If I set it below that width, it works, and if I set it above 0.27" (26 pixels), it works. It is very odd and is keeping my workbook from printing to PDF properly due to the margins. My workbook is not protected or locked.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to set the width 3 times in a row: `For i = 1 To 3: Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 0.25: Next i` Excel has some weirdness with setting the width correctly. 3 times in a row is usually getting it.

Comment: Note that the unit of the ColumnWidth is not inch. One unit of column width is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style. For proportional fonts, the width of the character 0 (zero) is used. See [Range.ColumnWidth property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, PEH- your answer worked great. I adjusted the width to 2.2 for my document settings and it did the trick. I really appreciate it!